# Conversion between Message and String in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, network-programming, handler

I'm trying to monitor network connectivity on android. This cannot be done on the main thread, so the data collection occurs on a separate thread I spawn - and I'm learning to use the Handler class to report back to the UI every second. Here's the relevant snippets of my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;
    private int linkSpeed;
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Message message = msg;
            textView.setText(message);
            setContentView(textView);

        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(25);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (;;) {
                    try {
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        while (true)
                        {
                            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                            if (wifiInfo != null) {
                                linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
                            }
                            else {
                                linkSpeed = -1;
                            }

                    }
                        String message = "linkSpeed = " + linkSpeed;
                        handler.handleMessage(message);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
```

The problem is, the message I get from the new thread I spawn is of type "String", but I cannot seem to overload the handleMessage method in the Handler class to take Strings instead of Messages. I don't think there's a direct conversion between Strings and Messages, as the only method in the Message class that returns a String is the toString() method, but it returns a description, rather than what the message contains. I'm also confused as to how I can convert a String to a Message - and I feel like I'm doing a very roundabout approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have to overload or try to do any coversions between `String` and `Message`. 
What you should do, is to put that String into an object of type Message and sent it to the `Handler`. Then in `handleMessage()` extract the String from the Message.

Something like this:

```
// ....
String message = "linkSpeed = " + linkSpeed;
Message msg = Message.obtain(); // Creates an new Message instance
msg.obj = message; // Put the string into Message, into "obj" field.
msg.setTarget(handler); // Set the Handler
msg.sendToTarget(); //Send the message
//....
```

And in `handleMessage()`:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    String message = (String) msg.obj; //Extract the string from the Message
    textView.setText(message);
    //....
}
```

But besides this, the program has an issue: you won't be able to send the data to the handler because that part of the code is unreachable:

```
while (true) {
    WifiInfo s = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    //..
}
String message = "linkSpeed = " + linkSpeed; // This line never won't be reached.
```

Also, don't forget to stop the `Thread` at some time, otherwise it will continue to run even after the app is closed.

Comment: I got it to work. That was really simple and helpful, thanks a bunch! I didn't actually use the handler class, I just called runOnUiThread within the try block to display texts from the main thread.

Answer (score 9):

You can attach objects - like your String - to your Message objects using a Bundle.

I have created this example:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

            String text = bundle.getString("key");

            // text will contain the string "your string message"
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Message message = handler.obtainMessage();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key", "your string message");

                message.setData(bundle);

                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
}
```